# Сортировка свойств CSS в Sublime Text 3 в алфавитном порядке

Tags: css, ubuntu, sublime-text

Использую для веб-разработки ноутбук на Ubuntu. Поставил Sublime Text 3, решил отсортировать CSS свойства, как на Windows 7, клавишей F9, но что-то не выходит. F5 тоже не помогает. Какую клавишу/комбинацию клавиш использовать?

Comment: fn + f9  у меня тоже ubuntu

Comment: [**CSSComb**](https://habrahabr.ru/post/230589/).

Comment: @Mr Robot, Вам принципиально нужно сортировать именно в алфавитном порядке? Вам так удобнее работать? См. [**опрос веб-разработчиков**](https://css-tricks.com/new-poll-how-order-css-properties/) и [**его итоги**](https://css-tricks.com/poll-results-how-do-you-order-your-css-properties/). Большинству удобнее группировать свойства CSS по типам; группировка по типам получила голосов в 4 раза больше нежели группировка в алфавитном порядке. Пакеты для Sublime Text, группирующие именно по типам, CSS Comb и CSS Order, [**пример**](https://github.com/lightningtgc/sublime-cssorder#effect). Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных, да, удобнее работать со свойствами, группируя их именно в алфавитном порядке.